# Breadth First Search returning incorrect amount

Tags: c++, algorithm, breadth-first-search

My implementation of breadth first search isn't returning the correct number for the shortest steps. I can't seem to figure out why. At first I assumed it was something to do with the way I was using the steps counter, but that seems right to me. Any insight would be greatly appreciated:

```
 struct vertices{
int value;
int parent;
int visited;
int distance;
};

 int BFS(vertices *v, int **adj_matrix, int num_nodes)
{

int target;
vertices current;
bool found = false;
int steps = 0;
int size = 0;

cin >> target >> num_nodes;
adj_matrix [num_nodes][num_nodes];
deque<vertices> q;

// Mark all the vertices as not visited
for(int i = 0; i < num_nodes; i++){
    v[i].visited = 0;
    v[i].distance = 0;
    v[i].parent = 0;
}

v[0].visited = 1;
v[0].distance = 0;
q.push_front(v[0]);

while(!q.empty()){
    current = q.front();
    q.pop_front();

    for(int i=0; i<num_nodes; i++){
        if(adj_matrix[current.value][i] ==1){
            if(v[i].visited == 0){
                 steps++;
                v[i].visited = 1;
                v[i].distance = current.distance + 1;
                v[i].parent = current.value;
                q.push_back(v[i]);

            }

            if(current.value == target){
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}

return steps;
}
```

Comment: Is `v[i].distance` meant to be the distance from the root of the search tree?

Comment: @Codor Yes. Although I'm updating after every vertex is visited, I realized don't actually do anything with that value

Comment: It's unclear what you are actually trying to do. What is the "number for the shortest steps"?

Comment: The shortest route to a target node is what I'm trying to find. @Henrik

Comment: How about `return v[target].distance;`?

Comment: @Henrik That ended up returning a 0 every time

Comment: I assume you have `v[i].value == i` for all `i`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is in a portion of the main method. @Henrik

Answer (score 1):

```
        if(v[i].visited == 0){
             steps++;
            v[i].visited = 1;
            v[i].distance = current.distance + 1;
            v[i].parent = current.value;
            q.push_back(v[i]);

             if(v[i].value==target) //try adding these two lines of code *
                return v[i].distance;

        }
```

*they are supposed to return distance of target node immediately after visiting target node.If BFS does not give you right answer check your adj. matrix if your targeted node is reachable.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you count `steps` and do not return `v[target].distance`. It is suppose to be the same number, isn't it ? You say in your comment that when you return `v[target].distance` you obtain 0. Are you sure that you keep the correct value, or there are some problems with

```
v[i].visited = 1;
v[i].distance = current.distance + 1;
v[i].parent = current.value;
```

Or if the distance of your target is really 0, that means you never reach the end, that's why your `steps` are not correct.
try to print some intermediate value